# Disable DefaultDoc using powershell in IIS6

Tags: powershell, iis-6

I have script to create apps in IIS6. Now we are developing in MVC and I need to disable (uncheck) the default document using the same script. I can't find the way to do it.

I create the app using this code:

```
$app = $path.Create("IIsWebVirtualDir", $AppNom)
$app.AppCreate2(1)
$app.Put("AppFriendlyName", $AppNom)
$app.Put("Path", $AppPath)
$app.Put("DefaultDoc", "$AppDefDoc")
$app.Put("AppPoolId", "$AppPoolNom")
$app.SetInfo()
```

Comment: You want to remove the default document? So IIS doesn't know what to load when the page is visited?

Comment: I need to disable because with MVC we can't have this feature enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it's pretty easy, if you already have a application configured:

```
$vDirName = "App"
$iisWebSite = Get-WmiObject -Namespace 'root\MicrosoftIISv2' -Class IISWebServerSetting -Filter "ServerComment = '$siteName'"
$iisVD = "IIS://LocalHost/$($iisWebSite.Name)/ROOT/$vDirName"    
$app = [adsi] $iisVD
$app.DirBrowseFlags.Set_Value("62")
$app.Commitchanges()
```